# Linux PHP create file permissions denied

Tags: php, linux, youtube, file-permissions

I am working on Ubuntu and trying to get a PHP script working that will allow the user to input a Youtube video URL, and the script will download the flv and convert it using youtube2mp3 (which I found here: http://hubpages.com/hub/Youtube-to-MP3-on-Ubuntu-Linux ).  I have been getting errors which I'm sure are permissions based, and I would like to know the best and most secure way to correct them.  Right now I'm calling

```
echo system("youtube-dl --output=testfile.flv --format=18 $url");
```

just to try and get the downloading portion working.  What shows up on the following page is

```
[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] xOMEi2g_oEU: Downloading video webpage
[youtube] xOMEi2g_oEU: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] xOMEi2g_oEU: Extracting video information
[youtube] xOMEi2g_oEU: Extracting video information
```

before showing the rest of my (irrelevant) output.  In the apache error log, I'm getting

```
ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 13]
    Permission denied: u'testfile.flv.part'
```

which is obviously indicative of a permissions issue.  Do I have to chown the directory in question to www-user?  Is that secure?  Or should I chmod the directory instead?  Eventually I will be putting this on a public facing server and I don't want any vulnerabilities in my implementation.  Any and all advice and answers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: forgot to mention, I looked through the youtube-dl source here: http://www.xtga.net/downloads/youtube-dl and the script appears to be using urllib2 to do the file downloading, I doubt that's very relevant though as I'm pretty sure this is a matter of what user is executing the command, slash what their permissions allow

Answer (score 4):

This is running as the user running the php process so two things:

1. Make sure this user has access to the directory you are writing your testfile out to.  I would specify a path that is isolated and not part of the web server directory structure which it appears to be doing now
2. Is `$url` coming from user input?  If it is I would then use `escapeshellcmd` on the entire string to ensure there isn't the random `rm -rf *` command in there.

Comment: How would I find the user running the php process?  If, in my script, I put "echo exec("whoami");" it prints www-user, would that be the user?  I'm going to create a new folder, /var/videofiles/, how would I make sure that the user has access to it?  chmod it?

Comment: After some googling around I used ps aux | grep apache and the user was www-data, so that's the user that's running apache/php?  My directory /var/videofiles/ has r-x in the 3 most right columns for its permissions, should I chmod it so that that part reads rw- ?

Answer (score 0):

chown can be used only by a superuser so if it's convenient you can use it, but servers don't normally run as superusers so I would go for chmod.

Answer (score 0):

Both of @Wes's suggestions are worth following; you don't want some goofball to supply an url like `||nc -l 8888 | sh &` and log in to your system a second later.

I strongly recommend confining your configuration with a tool such as [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SElinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/). Any of these [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) tools can prevent an application from writing in specific locations, executing arbitrary commands, reading private data, etc.

As I've worked on the AppArmor system for a decade, it's the one I'm most familiar with; I believe you could have a profile for your deployment put together in half a day or so. (It'd take me about ten or fifteen minutes, but like I said, I've been working on AppArmor for a decade. :)

Comment: I read the first few paragraphs of the wikipedia MAC page and browsed through the AppArmor site... I understand the general idea of MAC but the apparmor site just overwhelmed me.  What I'm working on is just a basic LAMP script plus the youtube2mp3 capability, I don't really know where to begin securing that, I already do input validation and sanitization but it couldn't hurt to have AppArmor in place I'm sure.

Comment: @dude, perhaps learning by example on a smaller program would help; try `apt-get install xpdf` to install the old `xpdf` PDF viewer, then run `aa-genprof xpdf` in one terminal, and `xpdf /path/to/a/file.pdf &` in another terminal. Answer the questions, restart the program a few times, try thing out, and see if it makes sense after a while. :) You can always get back to the way it was with `rm /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.xpdf ; /etc/init.d/apparmor reload`.

Comment: Thank you @sarnold, right now I'm rushing on getting a proof of concept out the door to hopefully get a software development internship this summer, but once I've got applications and a reasonable demo distributed I will be coming back to your comment and learning AppArmor as you described.  Thanks again :)